# Steps to implement FCFS algorithm in C using virtual memory (A Simulation)

Tags: c, memory-management, scheduling, virtual-memory

I don't necessarily want code but I want help with the workflow of the aforementioned program.
Suppose I have a `processes.txt` file with 4 processes(Process attributes: `Pid, AT,BT, Mamimum Memory Requirements`), and I want to implement the `FCFS` algorithm on these as well as use the Virtual memory memory management technique, How am I supposed to Implement it. I can statically implement `FCFS` without memory management but need assistance with the Virtual memory part

Comment: Hi! I think we need a lot more information to help you with this problem. Is this homework? If so, and you mention that, that will definitely help you get the right kind of answers to your question.

What is the aforementioned program? What is the development environment (Windows, Linux, Bare  Metal)? Can you explain how you've implemented it statically without memory management? Its not clear what the "Virtual memory part" is either.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for architecture and or algorithm dev help on something that has not yet been implemented. (No code, just discussing ideas.)  Suggest reading [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).